# Extend a 2D-matrix to a 3D-matrix by multiplying with a vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

Here what I would like to achieve:

I have a matrix C

```
C=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
```

And a vector `a`

```
a=[1 2];
```

I would like to make such an operation, that each element of the `a` vector is multiplied with `C` ( scalar multiplication ) and out comes a 3-dimensional array `D`:

```
(:,:,1) =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9


(:,:,2) =

     2     4     6
     8    10    12
    14    16    18
```

It would certainly work with a loop, but, since I'll need this operation on multiple occasions, a oneliner would be a great saver.

Answer (score 11):

This is a beautiful example for the use of [`bsxfun`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`reshape`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html). While @thewaywewalks proposes first calling `bsxfun` and reshaping the result, I'd suggest the opposite. This makes one of the key concepts of `bsxfun` - the singleton dimension expansion - more clear:

```
out = bsxfun(@times,C,reshape(a,1,1,[]))

ans(:,:,1) =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9


ans(:,:,2) =

     2     4     6
     8    10    12
    14    16    18
```

With `reshape(a,1,1,[])`, you make `a` be in the third dimension. If you now apply `bsxfun`, it will multiply the matrix `C` with each element of `a`.

Comment: Wouldn't `permute` be more appropriate than `reshape` here?

Answer (score 6):

Some [**`reshape`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html)'ing and some [**`bsxfun`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) will do:

```
out = reshape(bsxfun(@mtimes, C(:), a(:).'), [size(C),numel(a)] )
```

As suggested in [**hbaderts answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35555111/2605073) one could also use `bsxfun`'s capability of dimension expansion, and provide a permuted vector of factors:

```
out = bsxfun(@mtimes,C,permute(a,[3,1,2]))
```

---

```
out(:,:,1) =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9


out(:,:,2) =

     2     4     6
     8    10    12
    14    16    18
```

Answer (score 6):

I have another method for the benchmark compare... 
IMO it's the neatest way, at least for the syntax/readability term:

```
out = reshape(kron(a,C),[size(C),numel(a)]);

out(:,:,1) =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9


out(:,:,2) =

     2     4     6
     8    10    12
    14    16    18
```

Comment: I like it, but `kron` and readability.... only if you have some neat math background I'd say!

Comment: Or some honds-on experience with that useful function... :)

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT (BENCHMARKING):** Since several solutions (including mine below) have been suggested, here is some rough benchmarking to compare the different solutions, using larger arrays:

```
a=1:10;
N=1000; timers=zeros(N,6);
for ii=1:N; C=rand(400);
  tic; out = repmat(C,[1,1,numel(a)]).*reshape(repelem(a,size(C,1),size(C,2)),[size(C),numel(a)]); timers(ii,1)=toc;
  tic; out = bsxfun(@times,C,reshape(a,1,1,[])); timers(ii,2)=toc;
  tic; out = reshape(C(:)*a, size(C,1), size(C,2), numel(a)); timers(ii,3)=toc;
  tic; out = bsxfun(@mtimes,C,permute(a,[3,1,2])); timers(ii,4)=toc;
  tic; out = reshape(bsxfun(@mtimes, C(:), a(:).'), [size(C),numel(a)] ); timers(ii,5)=toc; 
  tic; out = reshape(kron(a,C),[size(C),numel(a)]); timers(ii,6)=toc;
end;

mean(timers)

ans =

    0.0080863    0.0032406    0.0041718     0.015166    0.0074462    0.0033051
```

... suggesting that  @hbaderts solution is fastest, then @Adiel's, then @Luis Mendo's, then @thewaywewalk's (1), then mine, then @thewaywewalk's (2).

**My solution:**

Another option, using [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) and [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) (no `bsxfun`):

```
out = repmat(C,[1,1,numel(a)]).*reshape(repelem(a,size(C,1),size(C,2)),[size(C),numel(a)])

out(:,:,1) =

 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 7     8     9

out(:,:,2) =

 2     4     6
 8    10    12
14    16    18
```

**This is the element-wise multiplication of two arrays.** The first is your original matrix `C` repeated `numel(a)` times in the third dimension:

```
repmat(C,[1,1,numel(a)])

ans(:,:,1) =

 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 7     8     9

ans(:,:,2) =

 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 7     8     9
```

The second is the same size as the first, with each slice containing the corresponding element of `a`:

```
reshape(repelem(a,size(C,1),size(C,2)),[size(C),numel(a)])

ans(:,:,1) =

 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 1     1     1

ans(:,:,2) =

 2     2     2
 2     2     2
 2     2     2
```

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is to use [matrix multiplication](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html) of `C` as a column vector times `a` as a row vector (this gives all element-wise products), and then [`reshape`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) the result:

```
out = reshape(C(:)*a, size(C,1), size(C,2), numel(a));
```